# PySide2: How to re-implement QFormLayout.takeRow()?

Tags: python-3.x, layout, pyside2, qformlayout

I've noticed that `QFormLayout` in Pyside2 does not have the `takeRow` method like its `PyQt5` counterpart. I've attempted to subclass `QFormLayout` to incorporate a similar method, but I've run into Runtime Errors, as the removal behavor of the `LabelRole` item is different than the `FieldRole` item. Another issue being that the `LabelRole` item does not actually get taken off the row even when the row itself is removed.

The following is the test sample I've been working with using Python 3.8.6:

```
from PySide2.QtWidgets import *
import sys


class MyFormLayout(QFormLayout):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MyFormLayout, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.cache = []
        print(f"Formlayout's identity: {self=}\nwith parent {self.parent()=}")

    def takeRow(self, row: int):
        print(f"Called {self.takeRow.__name__}")
        print(f"{self.rowCount()=}")
        label_item = self.itemAt(row, QFormLayout.LabelRole)
        field_item = self.itemAt(row, QFormLayout.FieldRole)
        print(f"{label_item=}\n{field_item=}")

        self.removeItem(label_item)
        self.removeItem(field_item)
        self.removeRow(row)  ## <-- This seems necessary to make the rowCount() decrement. Alternative?
        label_item.widget().setParent(None)  ## <-- Runtime Error Here?
        field_item.layout().setParent(None)

        self.cache.append(label_item.widget(), field_item)
        print(f"{self.rowCount()=}")
        print(f"{self.cache=}")
        print(self.cache[0])
        print("&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&")
        return label_item, field_item

    def restoreRow(self, insert_idx: int):
        print(f"Called {self.restoreRow.__name__}")
        print(f"{self.rowCount()=}")
        print(f"{self.cache=}")
        to_insert = self.cache.pop()
        self.insertRow(insert_idx, to_insert[0], to_insert[1])
        print("&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&")


class MyWindow(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MyWindow, self).__init__()
        self.mainlay = MyFormLayout(self)
        self.cmb = QComboBox()
        self.cmb.addItems(["Placeholder", "Remove 1 and 2"])
        self.cmb.currentTextChanged.connect(self.remove_rows_via_combo)
        self.current_text = self.cmb.currentText()
        self.hlay1, self.le1, self.btn1 = self.le_and_btn(placeholderText="1")
        self.hlay2, self.le2, self.btn2 = self.le_and_btn(placeholderText="2")
        self.hlay3, self.le3, self.btn3 = self.le_and_btn(placeholderText="3")
        self.hlay4, self.le4, self.btn4 = self.le_and_btn(placeholderText="4")
        self.remove_btn = QPushButton("Remove", clicked=self.remove_row_via_click)
        self.restore_btn = QPushButton("Restore", clicked=self.restore_a_row_via_click)
        self.mainlay.addRow("Combobox", self.cmb)
        for ii, hlayout in zip(range(1, 5), [self.hlay1, self.hlay2, self.hlay3, self.hlay4]):
            self.mainlay.addRow(f"Row {ii}", hlayout)
        self.mainlay.addRow(self.remove_btn)
        self.mainlay.addRow(self.restore_btn)

    @staticmethod
    def le_and_btn(**kwargs):
        hlay, le, btn = QHBoxLayout(), QLineEdit(**kwargs), QPushButton()
        hlay.addWidget(le)
        hlay.addWidget(btn)
        return hlay, le, btn

    def remove_row_via_click(self):
        self.mainlay.takeRow(1)

    def restore_a_row_via_click(self):
        self.mainlay.restoreRow(1)

    def remove_rows_via_combo(self, text):
        print(f"{self.remove_rows_via_combo.__name__} received the text: {text}")
        if text == "Remove 1 and 2":
            self.mainlay.takeRow(1)
            self.mainlay.takeRow(1)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    win = MyWindow()
    win.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

I would like to understand why the behavior of the role items is different and how the method may be properly re-implemented.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the label was created internally by Qt from a string, rather than by explicitly creating a `QLabel` in Python. This means that when the row is removed, the last remaining reference is also removed, which deletes the label on the C++ side. After that, all that's left on the Python side is an empty PyQt wrapper - so when you try to call `setParent` on it, a RuntimeError will be raised, because the underlying C++ part no longer exists.

Your example can therefore be fixed by getting python references to the label/field objects *before* the layout-item is removed:

```
class MyFormLayout(QFormLayout):
    ...    
    def takeRow(self, row: int):
        print(f"Called {self.takeRow.__name__}")
        print(f"{self.rowCount()=}")
        label_item = self.itemAt(row, QFormLayout.LabelRole)
        field_item = self.itemAt(row, QFormLayout.FieldRole)
        print(f"{label_item=}\n{field_item=}")
        
        # get refs before removal
        label = label_item.widget()
        field = field_item.layout() or field_item.widget()

        self.removeItem(label_item)
        self.removeItem(field_item)
        self.removeRow(row)

        label.setParent(None)
        field.setParent(None)

        self.cache.append((label, field))

        print(f"{self.rowCount()=}")
        print(f"{self.cache=}")
        print(self.cache[0])
        print("&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&")

        return label, field
```

Comment: Understood. Following this explanation and through testing, it was also clear that if `MyFormLayout` is part of some larger nested structure (i.e. it is within a widget of a QMainWindow), all widgets within a layout type of FieldRole would become owned by those "higher order" widgets. In such an event, I observed that it was necessary to have all widgets within this FieldRole layout also have `setParent(None)`. Otherwise, they would remain visible even when the FieldRole layout had its parent set to None. This is apparently due to the behavior of parent-child ownership.